# Expression list treated as compound expression in initializer

Tags: c++, initialization

I'm working with the following header and cpp file and want to use this server object in my code but am getting the error in the title.

header file

```
class XferServer {
 public:
    XferServer(const std::string& host, uint16_t port);
    ~XferServer(void);

    bool Init(void);
    bool AcceptBagRequest(StreamingBagSender* sender);

 private:
    std::string host_;
    uint16_t port_;

    int server_socket_fd_;
};
```

cpp file

```
XferServer::XferServer(const std::string& host, uint16_t port)
: host_(host)
, port_(port)
, server_socket_fd_(-1) {
}

XferServer::~XferServer(void) {

}
```

And this is what I am doing in my program but am getting errors

```
const std::string& host = "host";
uint16_t port = 30000;

include::streaming_xfer::XferServer* server(host,port);
```

Comment: Remove the asterisk from the variable definition.

Comment: why is `XferServer` a pointer in `include::streaming_xfer::XferServer* server(host,port);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this declaration there is declared a pointer that is a scalar object

```
include::streaming_xfer::XferServer* server(host,port);
                                  ^^^
```

You may not use a list `(host,port)` of more than one initializer in initialization of a scalar object.

Either you was going to declare an object of type `include::streaming_xfer::XferServer` like

```
include::streaming_xfer::XferServer server(host,port);
```

or a pointer like

```
include::streaming_xfer::XferServer* server = new include::streaming_xfer::XferServer(host,port);
```